# update html content in all duplicate id's Jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I am trying to update the HTML content inside div using jquery HTML function.

```
<div id="test"></div>
.
.
.
<div id = "test" style="display:none"></div>'
```

When I am updating the content.

```
 (#test).html(result)
```

I need to update both the div .How can I achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Don't duplicate IDs, they must be unique. Use a class instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID must be unique, you should use class instead

```
<div class="test" id="test1"></div>
<div class="test" id="test2"></div>

$('div.test')
.html('<p>All new content.You want!</p>');
```

Answer (score 1):

`Id` must be unique in `HTML`, you should use class instead

HTML:

```
<div class="test"></div>
.
.
.
<div class= "test" style="display:none"></div>'
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".test").html(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class instead of ids and try this

```
 $('.test').html(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('div').html(result);
```

or

Instead of id you can use class.

```
$("div.class_name").html(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your html code are:

```
<div id="#test">xxxx</div><div id="test">cccc</div>
```

then if you call $("#test"); these will return array with 2 length; so, you had to call each array to update all. I asumme you will update with value 'ddd' to both of #test, then

```
for(i=0;i<$('#test').length;i++){
      $('#test')[i].html('ddd');
}
```